# Static Hangfire RecurringJob methods in LINQPad are not behaving

Tags: hangfire, linqpad, hangfire-sql, linqpad7

I have a script in LINQPad that looks like this:

```
var serverMode = EnvironmentType.EWPROD;
var jobToSchedule = JobType.ABC;
var hangfireCs = GetConnectionString(serverMode);
JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage(hangfireCs);

Action<string, string, XElement> createOrReplaceJob =
    (jobName, cronExpression, inputPackage) =>
    {
        RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(jobName);
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            jobName,
             () => new BTR.Evolution.Hangfire.Schedulers.JobInvoker().Invoke(
                     jobName,
                     inputPackage,
                     null,
                     JobCancellationToken.Null),
            cronExpression, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
    };

// psuedo code to prepare inputPackage for client ABC...

createOrReplaceJob("ABC.CustomReport.SurveyResults", "0 2 * * *", inputPackage);

JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs().Where( j => j.Id.StartsWith( jobToSchedule.ToString() ) ).Dump( "Scheduled Jobs" );
```

I have to schedule in both QA and PROD.  To do that, I toggle the `serverMode` variable and run it once for `EWPROD` and once for `EWQA`.  This all worked fine until recently, and I don't know exactly when it changed unfortunately because I don't always have to run in both environments.

I did purchase/install LINQPad 7 two days ago to look at some C# 10 features and I'm not sure if that affected it.

But here is the problem/flow:

1. Run it for `EWQA` and everything works.
2. Run it for `EWPROD` and the script (Hangfire components) seem to run in a mix of QA and PROD.

When I'm running it the 'second time' in `EWPROD` I've confirmed:

1. The `hangfireCs` (connection string) is right (pointing to PROD) and it is assigned to `JobStorage.Current`
2. The query at the end of the script, `JobStorage.Current.GetConnection().GetRecurringJobs()` uses the right connection.
3. The `RecurringJob.*` methods inside the `createOrReplaceJob` Action use the connection from the **previous** run (i.e. `EWQA`).  If I monitor my QA Hangfire db, I see the job removed and added.

Temporary workaround:

1. Run it for `EWQA` and everything works.
2. **Restart LINQPad or use 'Cancel and Reset All Queries' method**
3. Run it for `EWPROD` and now everything works.

So I'm at a loss of where the issue might lie.  I feel like my upgrade/install of LINQPad7 might be causing problems, but I'm not sure if there is a different way to make the `RecurringJob.*` static methods use the 'updated' connection string.

Any ideas on why the restart or reset is now needed?

LINQPad - 5.44.02
Hangfire.Core - 1.7.17
Hangfire.SqlServer - 1.7.17

Comment: Have you tried to execute RecurringJob methods directly, e.g. not inside an anonymous callback? I don’t see anything related to Hangfire – yes, it uses static fields, but I have no idea why something is changed in the middle of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by your script (or a library that you call) caching something statically, and not cleaning up between executions.

Either clear/dispose objects when you're done (e.g., JobStorage.Current?) or tell LINQPad not to re-use the process between executions, by adding `Util.NewProcess=true;` to your script.

Comment: I will give it a try (`Util.NewProcess=true`), but this script has been used for last couple years without change.  I don't think I've updated the Hangfire Nuget packages either, but I can't 100% guarantee that.